# Does Google analytics track users with Tor browser?

Tags: google, traffic-analysis

I have visited some of my sites with the Tor browser and checked Google Analytics(GA4) to track the activity in real-time.
but I did not have any data in my G.A panel!
Is it reasonable that G.A ignores the data of Tor's users?

Answer (score 0):

It **does** - it tracks all it can *regardless* of the way the website was accessed. So - when you're having a website in both Clearnet and Darknet(not just Tor, it's right for I2P and ZeroNET, e.t.c.. either) - you make a *server-side* filtering to exclude *any* tracking code. Then it works well in both worlds